# How to get the nth line from a file and save the result to a variable

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

So, I am creating a script in bash and I am trying to read a text file which is saved in the same directory. I need to read the `nth` line of that file and then save it to a variable to be used later but I'm not sure how I can do this

What I have currently tried is listed below but it essentially reads the line from the file, saves it a variable and then deletes that line from the file and repeats. This is a hack and although it works, isn't what I want, I can't get the `nth value` and it's deleting from the file which I definitely don't want.

```
read -r first<"test.txt"      // reads first line and stores in first
sed -i -e "1d" "test.txt" .   // removes first line
read -r second<"test.txt"     // reads first line and stores in second  
sed -i -e "1d" "test.txt" .   // removes first line
```

If I wanted to get the 2nd line for example, I have seen `sed '2q;d' file` but not sure how/where the result is saved. It gets printed in terminal? Any help appreciated, thanks!w

Comment: You can also write that sed as `sed -n '2{p;q}'` which I find (a little) more obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '2q;d' file
```

prints the second line in `file` to the terminal.

To populate a variable with it, use bash's command expansion feature:

```
$ var=$(sed '2q;d' file)
$ echo "$var"
this is second line
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using `head` and `tail`:

```
a=$(head -2 test.txt | tail -1 )
```

Saves the second line of test.txt to the variable `$a`.